# Is the Atomic Blimp available for PS4 and XB1 owners?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, ps4, xbox-one

Rockstar announced bonus content for returning players and I pre-ordered the PC version. In [their post](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/52337/details-on-exclusive-content-for-returning-gtav-players-on), the Atomic Blimp was not mentioned but another one, Xero Blimp was introduced. Are they the same thing? Or can I fly both of them in the next-gen GTA V?

I have an Xbox 360 and got the Atomic Blimp code. Please help if you have a PS4/X1 and got the bonus for returning players already! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is this "next-gen" you speak of? What platform is this question for? I'm assuming PC, so I'll tag it as such; feel free to change or remove that if I tagged it in error. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your clarification! I used the term "next-gen" because R* posted "Details on Exclusive Content for Returning GTAV Players on PS4, Xbox One and PC", which seems that the deal is to all these 3 platforms. Nobody can confirm the bonus while the PC one isn't released yet. So I'm asking if PS4/X1 players got 2 blimps or just the re-skin one, Xero Blimp.

Comment: Got it, I'll retag it as such, thanks for the headsup :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Atomic Blimp](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Atomic_Blimp) and [Xero Blimp](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Xero_Blimp) are two different aircraft in GTA V. If you are playing on Xbox One or PS4 and have also played on Xbox 360 or PS3 then you should have access to both aircraft. If you have only played on Xbox One, PC or PS4 the Xero blip will be the only aircraft available.

As a returning player to unlock the Atomic Blimp you must have connected to Rockstar game services while playing on both a previous generation console (X360, PS3) and a current generation console (XB1, PS4). Rockstar services should recognize this for you and unlock the blimp.

Comment: I have the PC version and am not a returning player. However, I have access to the Atomic Blimp.